# MATLAB function that returns complete solution to Ax=b

Tags: matlab

I have a homework assignment that tasks me with writing a MATLAB function and I'm worried that I've missed something in my current answer. The function returns the complete solution to a linear equation of the form Ax=b, where A is a square matrix, and b is a vector of the appropriate dimension. The first line of the function is

```
function [Bs, Ns] = a(A, b)
```

where `Bs` is the basic solution (a vector), and `Ns` is the null solution - a matrix whose columns are a basis of the null space of A. There are also a few considerations in terms of the code used:

- Code will be marked based on a set of test cases.
- Built-in functions may be used in the code but it must be my original work.
- Code that produces an error or warning, such as for a singular matrix, will be assigned a failing mark.
- It can be assumed the test set will contain matrices that are all zero, non-singular, and otherwise rank deficient (complete solution exists, but MATLAB will produce an error or warning).

The code I've written is below.

```
function [Bs, Ns] = a(A, b)
ncols = size(A, 2);
x = pinv(A)*b;
Bs = x;
if ncols == rank(A)
    Ns = zeros(ncols,1);
else
    Ns = null(A);
end
end
```

The simplicity of my function has me worried that I've missed something (assignment is worth 4% of final grade) - either in my interpretation of the listed considerations, or that there are test cases which will cause errors/warnings. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it should work? Is this a programming class or a linear algebra class?

Comment: My two cents: give some meaningful name to your function

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks for having a look. It's a computer science class focused on linear algebra - "scientific computing".

Comment: @brainkz I agree that would be an improvement, but we're instructed to use that function name.

Comment: Only thing I'd wonder if when they meant "built" in functions, they wanted something a bit more primitive. You can do a singular value decomposition on A and use that to calculate the nullspace and the pseudo inverse. Your current code actually calculates the svd 3 times :P Once for 'pinv', once for 'rank', and once for 'null'

Comment: Instead of `pinv` consider also `A\b` (note not division `A/b`)

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's what OP is trying to code

Comment: @percusse The amount of different algorithms to solve `Ax=b` is huge. If `A\b` can not be used, the best way is to go to the docs, and read how `mldivide` does the job.However, without knowing which is the `A` matrix case, its hard to choose a good solver

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's why this is a homework

Comment: Not that `A\b` will produce warnings if the matrix is singular or nearly singular. If you use that, then you'll need to ensure that you check the `rank` and possibly the condition (`cond`) before doing `A\b`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri He should take a singular value decomposition anyway to determine rank and null space. Once you have the svd, calculating the pseudo inverse is basically two matrix multiples. But yes, in the general case, you don't want to calculate inverses and multiply, you want to solve linear systems more directly.